# Dokku mirgate to a new droplet

Tags: dokku

What should I do if I migrate to a new droplet?

After migrate to a new droplet in digital ocean I have this error:

```
MacBook-Pro-Anton:tm ipatov$ git push dokku master
ssh: connect to host sitename port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seems to be a problem with connection.

remember that if you moved to another droplet the application, you have to change the dokku remote to point to the new IP or address of that new server